# Trying to create sprites at a random x location without overlapping in c

Tags: c, sprite

So I am trying to create a level of platforms using sprites, each of them are created randomly along the screen at the same y location. Although, the issue that I am having is that when they are created randomly they constantly overlap and I can't seem to find a way to create them so that they cannot be overlapping.

My program currently creates a sprite at a random x location, then a for loop creates the specified amount of platforms. My question is if I wanted to stop them overlapping would I need to try make a constraint during the random x specification or during the for loop which creates the multiple sprites.

New to c so really stuck on the logic for this one, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have AABB (axis-aligned bounding box) collision detection you can employ to detect overlaps?

Comment: Can't you just add some logic to make sure the next random X position is greater than the previous X position + the platform width / 2 ?

Comment: Not yet, i'm relatively new to c so my only idea for detecting a collision was to define x location of say sprite 1 and say sprite 2 x location != x of sprite 1

Comment: How about breaking your X axis into N separate regions, and placing a sprite at a random location within each?

Answer (score 0):

(you gave this as a math/algorithm question, so I will provide a math answer, not a ready C program :), enjoy coding it - and ask a question here if you get stuck )

To put it simply, you want to generate a list of M numbers (x positions for M platforms, in your case) in the range 0..N-1, so that these numbers are all different. Obviously M < N.

For the first one you have N possible choices,  for the second you have N-1 choices (one being taken), for the third N-2, etc.

There are many ways to do that, but here is a simple one:

fill an array on N integers with the numbers 0..N-1 (so that `a[i] == i` for all values of `i`).

Now, set n = N-1 and do this M times:

- take a random number r in the range (0..n), and use a[r] as the next choice
- remove a[r] from the array, by shifting everything from a[r+1] to the end by one position.
- decrement n ( `n--`)

(each time the loop will be choosing from a list that has fewer and fewer numbers, with exactly the ones that were picked before being left out)

Comment: That would work, although after reading the task and having to increase complexity in having more than one platform type I think what I need is definitely a way to detect an overlap or collision. So I would somehow say if sprite 2 overlaps sprite 1, sprite 2 x = sprite 1 x -1